# Create folder (mkdir) and move a file into this (rename)

Tags: php, rename, mkdir

I searched on StackOverflow but I have not found a solution to my problem .. 
I should create a directory (if not already present), and move a file (.Zip) previously created on this new folder

- I create the zip file correctly
- I create the new directory correctly (if not present)
- I move the zip file properly in the new directory, but sometimes, when I have to either create the folder, and move the file, the folder is created, but the file is not moved, probably because the command is executed before the folder is created

I tried the following solutions

```
//create zip
Zip('editor', 'backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip');
//create folder
mkdir('backup', 0777, true);
//move file
rename('backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip', 'backup/backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip');



//create zip
Zip('editor', 'backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip');
//create folder
$ret = mkdir('backup', 0777, true);
//move file
rename('backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip', 'backup/backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip');



//create zip
Zip('editor', 'backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip');
//create folder
$ret = mkdir('backup', 0777, true);
//move file
move_backup();

function move_backup(){

     rename('backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip', 'backup/backup_'.date("d_m_Y__H_i_s").'.zip');

}
```

### UPDATE : SOLUTION

```
  @date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
  $my_time = date("d_m_Y__H_i_s");


  function Zip($source, $destination){
      ....
  }

  function sposto_backup($t){

    rename('backup_'.$t.'.zip', 'backup/backup_'.$t.'.zip');

  }


  Zip('editor', 'backup_'.$my_time.'.zip');

  if (!file_exists('backup')) {
       $r = mkdir('backup', 0777, true);
       sposto_backup($my_time);
  }else{
    sposto_backup($my_time);
  }
```

Comment: Only thing which comes to mind is that you calculate the `date` value repeatedly.  If the microseconds are such that in the fraction of a second between calls, it goes to the next second, then you'll be working with different files.

Comment: @Jeremy Miller I try to save the date() result in a variable!

Comment: By that, you mean that it now works as desired, so you have a solution to the question, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a permissions problem - if you enabled error reporting or trapped errors in your code then you might be able to identify the problem yourself.

Comment: I think it isn't a permission problem, since most of the time everything works

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving your mkdir()'s into if statements since the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) shows that mkdir returns true on success. This means that once the mkdir function has successfully executed, the content inside the if statement will execute.

```
if(mkdir('backup', 0777, true))
{

}
```

or

```
if($ret = mkdir('backup', 0777, true))
{

}
```